State space model of DC Motor
I was wondering if it possible to obtain the state space model of a hobby DC motor(brushed). Can anyone guide me through the steps if possible?

First, there's a lot of material out there -- have all of the results on a search of "model a DC motor" been unsatisfactory?  Second, an accurate model of the behavior of a system that has a DC motor embedded in it depends on how the motor is driven (basically, what the drive output impedance is if it's linear, or it's nonlinear characteristics if it's PWM) and what the motor is driving (specifically, the effective moment of inertia of the motor and its mechanical load, and the damping of the load if it's significant).  So -- do  a search, then tell us more about the system.

You need certain motor variables https://i.sstatic.net/BH1uRr9z.jpg

From my understanding, i need
R - Armature Resistance
L - Armature Inductance
Kₑ - Back EMF Constant
Kₜ - Torque Constant
b - Viscous Friction Coefficient
J - Moment of Inertia
I'm unsure of how to proceed with the measurement of Kt and J. I have a DMM and LCR-Q meter with me. I also have a tachometer so i think i can measure the rest.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/441718/what-is-the-state-space-model-for-a-bldc-motor?rq=1

A transfer function models the response of inputs to outputs. For a brushed DC motor you have current and voltage in and torque and speed out.
To find the transfer function of the motor, you need to measure the inputs and the outputs while knowing what the speed and torque load is.
You can then use system identification to find the transfer function.
But there are easier ways. PID's usually work well because most motor transfer functions are first order or linear enough to control. I'd try a PID first and then do the harder things.

My aim isn't to design a controller, I want to explore state-space modelling and LQR design.
